# I need to setup ratelimiting in controller level for an API's but with certain condition check wheather have to apply ratelimiting or not

Tags: java, spring-boot, rate-limiting, whitelist, resilience4j

Till now I have setup these, but it result in ratelimiting without any conditions

```yaml
resilience4j.ratelimiter:
  instances:
    basic:
      limitForPeriod: ${RATE_LIMIT_PERMISIBLE_HITS:1000}
      limitRefreshPeriod: ${RATE_LIMIT_REFRESH_RATE:1h}
      timeoutDuration: ${RATE_LIMIT_TIMEOUT:20s}
      registerHealthIndicator: ${RATE_LIMIT_HEALTH_INDICATOR:true}
      eventConsumerBufferSize: ${RATE_LIMIT_EVENT_BUFFER:100}
```

```java
@PostMapping
@RateLimiter(name = "basic", fallbackMethod = "rateLimiterFallback")
suspend fun getTradeEngineResponse(@Valid @RequestBody tradeEngineRequest: TradeEngineRequest): ResponseMessage {
    return Response<ResponseMessage>().ok(
            ResponseMessage(id = tradeEngineService.getTradeEngineResponse(tradeEngineRequest), message = SaasConstants.SUCCESS_MESSAGE)
    )
}
```

Expecting to have a flag before `@RateLimiter` annotation based on that apply ratelimiter